# Django orm count return only one result

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have this table named `Orders` with each order having a status and I want to count the results based on status:

```
status_counts = Order.objects.all( ).values( 'status' ).annotate(
    pending = Count( Case(
        When( status__exact = Order.STATUS_PENDING, then = F( 'pk' ) )
    ) ),
    completed = Count( Case(
        When( status__exact = Order.STATUS_COMPLETED, then = F( 'pk' ) )
    ) ),
    failed = Count( Case(
        When( status__exact = Order.STATUS_FAILED, then = F( 'pk' ) )
    ) ),
    reversed = Count( Case(
        When( status__exact = Order.STATUS_REVERSED, then = F( 'pk' ) )
    ) ) )
```

The problem with my query is that it returns a result for each status:

`[{'completed': 4571, 'pending': 0, 'failed': 0, 'reversed': 0, 'status': 0}, {'completed': 0, 'pending': 2278, 'failed': 0, 'reversed': 0, 'status': 1}, {'completed': 0, 'pending': 0, 'failed': 0, 'reversed': 353, 'status': 3}]`

Is there a way I can have this result:

`{'completed': 4571, 'pending': 2278, 'failed': 0, 'reversed': 353, 'status': 0}`

Comment: Unless this is being used in a high-volume request, I'd definitely suggest doing this in a series of distinct `count` queries. It's not as efficient, but it's far easier to reason about, and whoever maintains this code or even reads it next -- even if it's you, a month from now -- will definitely be able to interpret it more readily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if following works:

```
dict(Order.objects.all().values('status').annotate(scount=Count('status')).values_list('status', 'scount'))
```

**Breaking it down**

```
# get all available statuses
qs = Order.objects.all().values('status')

# annotate each status with count
qs = qs.annotate(scount=Count('status'))
# [{'status': 'completed', 'scount': 4571}, {'status': 'pending', 'scount': 2278} ...]

# now get only what you want in `values_list`
qs = qs.values_list('status', 'scount')
# [('completed', 4571), ('pending', 2278), ...]

# and then convert it to dict
result = dict(qs)
# {'completed': 4571, 'pending': 2278, ...}
```